# psftp batch script hangs on and off when scheduled from sql server agent

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a `psftp` script to get files from a server every hour.  The script works good when I manually run the bat file from its location and also runs well from the SQL Server Agent when I am logged in/monitoring it.

However, when am not logged in, the script hangs and continues to run forever, creating an empty log file.

Since this is an hourly run, this blocks out all subsequent runs as well creating delays in data load.

Could anyone advice what could possibly be causing this rather bizarre issue.

1. The log files created for each run are independent, with time stamp - so its not a lock out of log files causing the hanging.
2. Even though there is a prompt , a prompt file is supplied with value Y in it , that allows it to run without any requirement for explicitly entering a prompt value.
3. The script has been scanned for any pauses and other timeouts (Is not applicable really , since it works seamlessly when am logged in)
4. I tried setting set `--trust-model=always`, script still hangs when I am not logged in.

This said, I am not really sure if it has anything to do with me being logged in or if its just a coincidence. But basically, I am never able to catch the issue happening while am monitoring it!

Comment: Does the account running SQL Server Agent have read/write access to every location that it will need in order to complete the script?

Comment: Yes it does. Infact,  when i manually trigger the sql server agent job to trigger the batch script - it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permission issue. Firstly check what user will be running the slq agent job when you are not logged in. Then ensure this user has full permissions/admin rights.

I think you might need admin to shell out - which I presume you are doing to run psftp.

Comment: Hi Kevin, if it was a permission issue would it not hang/break all the time ?And not now and then.? When i trigger the sql server agent job manually, it runs all too well ! That said, I've rechecked all its permissions and everything seems to be as expected...I am confused.

Comment: When i say trigger it Manually - the user used to run this is the same user as when it is scheduled run. I just start the job manually - user and permissions are the same for manual/ monitored/scheduled runs.

Comment: hi, If it was a permission issue would it not hang break all the time - no. You said that you can run this job manually, but that it will not run when scheduled. This implies to me that the user running the job when it runs manually has permission, but the user running the job when it is scheduled does not. Check what user the SQL server agent is running as - it is this user that be running the job when it is scheduled. It will normally be "network service", local system account or something like that.